# I need to write my name using * but i keep getting an error im very new to coding

Tags: java, eclipse

Keep getting the error "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module alex not found"

Not much im very new

```java
module alex {
    class main {

        public static void main(String[] args) { //
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("           ************      **      **********      **          **");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      **********       **        **");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      **                 **    **");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      **                  **  **");
              System.out.println("           ************      **      **********           ****");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      **********          **  **");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      **                 **    **");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      ***********       **      **");
              System.out.println("           **        **      **      ***********     **         **");
              System.out.println();
        }  //end main()
    } // end class}
}
```

Comment: if answer is correct then mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not proper for Java. It follows as

```
public class Demo{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("           ************      **      **********      **          **");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      **********       **        **");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      **                 **    **");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      **                  **  **");
          System.out.println("           ************      **      **********           ****");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      **********          **  **");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      **                 **    **");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      ***********       **      **");
          System.out.println("           **        **      **      ***********     **         **");
          System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Filename would be **Demo.java**

Now run your code in eclipse and if you try to execute it in terminal.

```
> javac Demo.java
> java Demo
```